# saving images after editing,that time saving only last edited images in winform application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am working on windows form application. I have a `GridView` like this:
[image]

in cell content click i wrote code like this:

```
If e.ColumnIndex = 4 Then
            Dim OFDLogo As New OpenFileDialog()
            OFDLogo.Filter = "JPEG(*.jpg)|*.jpg|BMP(*.bmp)|*.bmp"
            If OFDLogo.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                gv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(6).Value = Image.FromFile(OFDLogo.FileName)
            End If
        End If
```

and save button i wrote code like this:

```
Dim cmpny As String = "Delete from CompanyMaster_tbl"
        Exetransaction(cmpny)
    For i As Integer = 0 To gv.RowCount - 2
     sqlInsertT2 = "Insert Into DepartmentMaster_tbl(dtname,dtphone,dtEmail,Cid) Values ('" + myTI.ToTitleCase(gv.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value) + "','" + gv.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value + "','" + gv.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value + "'," & Ccid & ");"
                    Exetransaction(sqlInsertT2)
                    Dim departmnt As String = gv.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value

                    Dim departid As Integer = RecordID("dtId", "DepartmentMaster_tbl", "dtName", departmnt)
                    Dim sql As String

                    '----------------------------------

                    Dim image As Image = TryCast(gv.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value, Image)
                    If image IsNot Nothing Then
                        Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
                        image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif)
                        Dim imagedata As Byte() = ms.ToArray()
                        sql = "update DepartmentMaster_tbl set empimage=@photo where dtId='" & departid & "'"
                        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, con.connect)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@photo", SqlDbType.Image)
                        cmd.Parameters("@photo").Value = imagedata
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        con.disconnect()
                    End If
     Next
```

In first time I try to save this,saving both images, after loading the same page again I edited one image and I try to save, but that time only saving edited image What is wrong with my code?

```
In cell content click I am taking row_index
```

Comment: Could you be more clear about what isn't working?

Comment: sir first time both images are saving to data base..the i reload page again ..i try to edit one image..and i try to save again,,only edited image getting saving

Comment: in cell content click i am taking row_index..that's y happening like this?